# Custom close reason: Questions about characteristics of a specific language are off-topic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Each site is permitted three custom off-topic close reasons.  I'd like to propose one for questions about specific languages.

Comment: Whatever the wording, would "Is there a method to learn which grammatical gender a noun in French has?" http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/20/is-there-a-method-to-learn-which-grammatical-gender-a-noun-in-french-has be seen to be off topic according to this close reason?

Comment: This is a great proposal seeing as how we get so many of these misdirected questions.

Answer (score 4):

My proposed text (leave comments to suggest changes):

> Questions about **grammatical rules** or **specific characteristics of a language** are off-topic here. A *language-specific site*<sup>*</sup> is the appropriate place for these questions, or if such a site does not yet exist, you can propose one on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

<sup>*</sup>This text could/should link to a meta post detailing all of the language-specific sites which currently exist on SE. (Or a link to such a listing on stackexchange.com, but I can't find such a list, other than [this](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=language), which seems too broad).

Comment: If this happens, what will happen to the language-specific tags?

Comment: I have a list of language-specific SE sites [on my website](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/misc/stackexchange.html#languages) :-)

Comment: @PythonMaster: There's still a place for language-specific tags. There's just not a place for questions about grammatical rules and specific characteristics of a language.